# can i get the real IP address of the web server which is behide a load balancer?

Tags: http, ip, load-balancing, wan

The website have multiple location, I want to access the server located in HK or SG instead of USA. 
Is there anyway i can trace that ?

Comment: Do you the IP address of service behind a load balancer, or do you want to see where the service is available, and connect to a specific geography?

Answer (score 0):

Usually no. It is usually a private NATted IP address and you couldn't route to it anyway in that case.

If the load balancer is fronting public servers, then you may be able to figure it out, but probaby not from the load balancer. You'd have to figure it out by doing some detective work (unless you were forwarded via round robin DNS)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation